# Regular Expression: Treat a group as optional if its not present but if present only capture the previous group before that

Tags: regex, search, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have a requirement where I need to use Regex for parsing a query from user.

> For e.g. User could search for links with query format like

```
link to <keyword> from <person name>
link to <keyword> from <person name> shared <time>
```

e.g.

```
link to connect form from sandeep agarwal => keyword=connect form, person-name=sandeep agarwal
link to sharepoint ppt from mathews => keyword=sharepoint ppt, person-name=mathews 
link to sharepoint design from Gronvik yesterday => keyword=sharepoint design, person-name=Gronvik, time=yesterday
```

I have above mentioned the expected capturing group values.

> My Regex:
>
> "Link to (?[a-z ]+) from (?[]+)(?:shared)(? [a-z]+)"

Here is my response to above 3 queries

```
Match 1
Full match = link to connect link from sandeep agarwal
Group `keyword` = connect form
Group `name`= sandeep agarwal   

Match 2
Full match = link to sharepoint git from sapna
Group `keyword` = sharepoint ppt
Group `name`= mathews           

Match 3 - **This is where things go wrong**
Full match = link to sharepoint git from sapna grover shared yesterday
Group `keyword` = sharepoint design
Group `name`= Gronvik shared yesterday
```

> In the above mentioned 3rd response, I'm getting the "Gronvik shared
>   yesterday" as group "name" but the ideal scenario would be
>   name=Gronvik and time="yesterday" I have tried many approaches from
>   positive lookahead to lookbehind but something or the other scenarios
>   starts breaking.
>
> The keyword "shared" might not be present everytime but when it is
>   present, my "name" group should capture the name till shared(excluding
>   it) and group "time" should capture time only if "shared" is present
>   in the query. It would be really helpful if someone could point out
>   the right direction.

Comment: Your pattern is malformed as `[]+)(?:shared)(?<time> [a-z]` is a single big character class.

Comment: Try `(?i)^Link to (?<keyword>[a-z ]+) from (?<name>.*?)(?:(?:\s+shared)?\s+(?<time>[a-z]+))?$`, see [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fi%29%5eLink+to+%28%3f%3ckeyword%3e%5ba-z+%5d%2b%29+from+%28%3f%3cname%3e.*%3f%29%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3a%5cs%2bshared%29%3f%5cs%2b%28%3f%3ctime%3e%5ba-z%5d%2b%29%29%3f%24&i=link+to+connect+form+from+sandeep+agarwal%0d%0alink+to+sharepoint+ppt+from+mathews%0d%0alink+to+sharepoint+design+from+Gronvik+shared+yesterday&o=im)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks. Your demo seems to be working.I 'm facing issue  running it over https://regex101.com/r/cO8lqs/17896. I used that site to test my regex. Could you help me understand why it might not be working the same way it is working on your demo site?

Comment: I added an answer with full explanation and demo. The `^` and `$` anchors and the right optional grouping are crucial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?i)^Link\s+to\s+(?<keyword>[a-z ]+) from (?<name>.*?)(?:\s+shared\s+(?<time>[a-z]+))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cO8lqs/17910).

**Details**

- `(?i)` - case insensitive flag
- `^`  - start of string (or line if `m` multiline option is on)
- `Link to`  - literal text
- `(?<keyword>[a-z ]+)` - Group "keyword": 1+ letters or spaces
- `from`  - literal text
- `(?<name>.*?)` - Group "name": any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `(?:\s+shared\s+(?<time>[a-z]+))?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `shared` - a literal substring
  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `(?<time>[a-z]+)` - Group "time": 1+ letters
- `$` - end of string / line.

Comment: Your regex demo link in this answer is wrong for the first input. It is picking surname of the person under Time Group. Could you pls. check once

Comment: I tested it with c# console application, the first case is failing there too. I'm assuming that if it works on `https://regex101.com/`, then it will work on console app too. For a long time I have used that site as a play ground and I can trust its outputs in real world scenarios.

Comment: @Cyclotron3x3 You should reconsider your trust into regex101.com when you test .net regex as that site does not support .net regex syntax. Try `[\p{L}-[a]]+` regex against `bca` string, it won't work at regex101.com.

Comment: Thanks, it is working now. Curious to know why \h+ worked and why \s+ was not able to.

Comment: Because `\h` is not supported in .net regex. It matches horizontal whitespace. In .net, it is `[\p{Zs}\t]`.

Comment: The reason I said it is till now I did not have any bad experience with `regex101.com`. The pattern you initially shared was failing even in my console application. Result seems to match with whatever I test on the site. In past I have used it for Java/Python apps.

Comment: Yes, it is good enough for Python now, there used to be quite nasty bugs. For Java, you are missing out on constrained width lookbehinds and character class subtraction/intersections.

Answer (score 0):

`link to (.*?) from (.*?)( shared (.*))?$`

Use `.*?` for lazy repeaters (lazy = non-greedy)

Comment: This seems to be giving right results on `regexstorm.net/tester` but failing in `https://regex101.com/`. I tested it with creating C# console application, it is failing scenarios there too. Would you mind running it over https://regex101.com/